# How to extend an array with linear interpolation

Tags: python, arrays, interpolation

What I want is to extend an array of length m to an array of length `n (n>m)`, and interpolate the missing values linearly.

For example, I want to extend this array `[1,5,1,7]` to an array of length `7`, the result should be [1,**3**,5,**3**,1,**5**,7], where the bold figures result from linear interpolation.

Is there an easy way to do this in Python? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you want to get if you extend the array [1, 5, 1, 7] to an array of length 6?

Comment: You can write a simple logic for what you want rather than finding an "easy way".

Comment: Then it should be, [1, 1+(5-1) * 3/5, 5+(1-5) * 1/5, 5+(1-5) * 4/5, 1+(7-1) * 2/5, 7]

Comment: @Maytree23 If you know what you want to get why don't you just write the code?

Comment: I just wonder if there is a built-in function for convenience...please.

Comment: @Pranav Maytree23 might just be looking for a Pythonic way to it.

Comment: Thanks guys. Problem solved, please refer to @cfh 's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`interp`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.interp.html) function from numpy can do what you want.

Example:

```
>>> xp = [1, 2, 3]
>>> fp = [3, 2, 0]
>>> np.interp(2.5, xp, fp)
1.0
>>> np.interp([0, 1, 1.5, 2.72, 3.14], xp, fp)
array([ 3. ,  3. ,  2.5 ,  0.56,  0. ])
```

Comment: can you elaborate the answer a bit? how did you come to xp and fp and how do you account for the desired shape of the final array?