# replace zeros in numpy array with linear interpolation between its preceding and succeeding values

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, benchmarking

assuming that we have an array `a = np.array([1,2,0,4,0,5,0,0,11])` ,how can we get:

```
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  4.5,  5,  7,  9, 11])
```

What I have tried is:

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

a = np.array([1,2,0,4,0,5,0,0,11])
b = a[np.nonzero(a)]
brange = np.arange(b.shape[0])
interp = interp1d(brange, b)
```

This seems to do the actual job of finding in-between values. For instance:

```
print (interp(1), interp(1.5), interp(2), interp(2.5), interp(3))
#out: 2.0 3.0 4.0 4.5 5.0
```

But I can't figure out how to re-construct my original array from `interp`. I also tried the solution to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023326/how-to-extend-an-array-with-linear-interpolation), but I had the exact same problem with that solution as well.

**UPDATE:**

I did a quick benchmark for both solution using numpy and pandas, here is the result:

```
y = np.array([1,2,0,4,0,5,0,0,11])

def test1(y):

    x = np.arange(len(y))
    idx = np.nonzero(y)
    interp = interp1d(x[idx],y[idx])

    return interp(x)

def test2(y):
    s = pd.Series(y)
    s.interpolate(inplace=True)
    return s.values

%timeit t1 = test1(y)
%timeit t2 = test2(y)

139 µs ± 1.62 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
158 µs ± 2.01 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

About 12% faster. Not as good as I hoped, but since the code is going to be run several million times, it probably worth the effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your implementation is a bit off.  What you want is something closer to what @Thomas came up with:

```
y = np.array([1,2,0,4,0,5,0,0,11])
idx = np.nonzero(y)
interp = interp1d(x[idx],y[idx])

x = np.arange(len(y))
ynew = interp(x)
```

If you want to re-construct your original array from `interp`, you just need to use the `.x` and `.y` parameters.

```
a_ = np.zeros(interp.x[-1] + 1)
a_[interp.x] = interp.y
```

Of course, this will remove any trailing zeros from the original `a`, as `a.size` is not preserved in the interpolation.  If you have preserved them elsewhere (such as `ynew.shape`), you can instead initialize `a_ = np.zeros_like(ynew)`

Answer (score 5):

You need to feed `interp1d` a y-array *without* the zeros and an x-array that skips said zeros. Then, for the interpolation, you have to give the interpolation function an x-array that holds all the original x-values plus the ones at which you want your interpolated values to occur. In your case, as you have a ready, equally spaced vector, you can just use `np.arange` to produce the x-values and `np.where` for filtering out the zeros.

Here an example code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

y = np.array([1,2,0,4,0,5,0,0,11])
xnew = np.arange(len(y))

zero_idx = np.where(y==0)
xold = np.delete(xnew,zero_idx)
yold = np.delete(y, zero_idx)

print('before')
print(xold)
print(yold)

f = interp1d(xold,yold)

ynew = f(xnew)

print()
print('after')
print(xnew)
print(ynew)
```

The result looks like this:

```
before
[0 1 3 5 8]
[ 1  2  4  5 11]

after
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
[  1.    2.    3.    4.    4.5   5.    7.    9.   11. ]
```

**EDIT**:

Actually you don't need the `np.delete`, you can just use slicing:

```
y = np.array([1,2,0,4,0,5,0,0,11])
x = np.arange(len(y))
idx = np.where(y!=0)        #or np.nonzero(y) -- thanks DanielF
f = interp1d(x[idx],y[idx])
ynew = f(x)
```

Comment: or even `idx = np.nonzero(y)`

Answer (score 4):

you can use `pandas` `interpolate` function:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = pd.Series([1,2,0,4,0,5,0,0,11])

a.replace(0, np.NaN, inplace=True)

a.interpolate()

0     1.0
1     2.0
2     3.0
3     4.0
4     4.5
5     5.0
6     7.0
7     9.0
8    11.0
```

Also : `a.interpolate().values` will give you array of values.

```
# output: array([  1. ,   2. ,   3. ,   4. ,   4.5,   5. ,   7. ,   9. ,  11. ])
```

Also : `interpolate` takes `inplace` as an argument which you can use

Comment: Thank's for your answer. but I need a numpy solution without overhead of converting to `Series` if possible.

Comment: @AlirezaSohofi is `interp(5)` giving you the output you expect?

Comment: No, and that was actually the problem I had. check out @Daniel's solution and my update.

Comment: @AlirezaSohofi Thanks for the update. I still found the pandas interpolation much simpler. still thanks :)

Comment: I agree with you. I would never bother to do it in numpy way for one-off jobs, but for production code I think performance should be given priority.